# knockout tbody filter parent / childs

Tags: knockout.js, foreach, filter, nested

I have the following nested data structure ( viewmodel ):

```
projects ( projectid, project_name )
  |--- subprojects ( parent_projectid, subproject_name )
```

I want to filter the "subprojects" to "parent_projectid" which is the id from parent project ( "projectid" ). The "tbody" should render the subprojects automatically, such as :

```
     <tbody >
            <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: projectid"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: project_name "></td>
                <td class="add" href="#" data-bind="click: addsubproject">Add Subproject</td>
            </tr>

    *** here should the filter applied : ***    
             <!-- ko foreach: subprojects // show only subprojects with "parent_projectid = projectid" -->
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: parent_projectid"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: subproject_name "></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- /ko -->    
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
```

How can I apply this ? I dont want to compute something in viewmodel to get the filtered subprojects, the filter "mechanism" should work only in the rendering tbody ( if possible )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy once you stop thinking that your view should be smart. Your view should reflect your model - don't force it to do any more than that.

If you want to display this structure:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1.1
  - Child 1.2
- Parent 2

  - Child 2.1
  - Child 2.2

then that is how your model is supposed to look like. Build it accordingly:

```
// we only really have one type of object in your scenario, let's call it "Project"
function Project(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.children = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.children, function (child) {
        // NB this is recursive
        return new Project(child);
    }));
}

// this will be the main viewmodel
function ProjectTree() {
    var root = new Project({id: 0, name: "root", children: data});
    this.projects = root.children;
}
```

Assuming that the `data` you retrieve from the server is a flat array of project objects, let's pre-process them into a tree. Again - this is the key part - if you want to show tree-shaped data, you should have tree-shaped data.

```
$.get("projects.json").then(function (data) {
    var index = {}, children = {};
    // index objects by id and by parentid
    data.forEach(function (project) {
        index[project.id] = project;
        if (project.parentid in index) {
            children[project.parentid].push(project);
        } else {
            children[project.parentid] = [project];
        }
    });
    // link up everything into a tree
    Object.keys(index).forEach(function (project) {
        project.children = children[project.id] || [];
    });
    return children[0]; // or whatever the parent ID of top level projects is
}).done(function (data) {
    var vm = new ProjectTree(data);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Now the view can be what it is supposed to be - straight-forward:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: projects">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td class="add" href="#" data-bind="click: addsubproject">Add Subproject</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: children -->
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $parent.id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->    
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I dont understand the function "$.get("projects.json)" 


$.get("projects.json").then(function (data) 
{
 .....
 
}).done(function (data) 
{
    var vm = new ProjectTree(data);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});


I read my projects from sharepoint list ( reading all items into projects array ). I have a global variable "projectslist" which has project objects. Should I loop then through the "projectslist" and build the "tree structure" ?
And where should I place the function? In the main view model?

Comment: That jQuery `.get()` was just a placeholder for any way to retrieve a list of projects. Use whatever you have. You  could place it in the main viewmodel uf you want to, that's up to you. In my approach it's outside. The point of my answer aren't these kinds of implementation details.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, should I define a new viewmodel something like "tree" which contains all projects and subprojects? In that viewmodel "tree" I loop through all "projects" and assign all "childs" to every project.
Than I bind the new "tree" to the tbody table.. Is that a good way ?

Tree 
   |--- Project 1  
           |--- Subproject 1.1 
           |--- Subproject 1.2  
   |-- Project 2  <br>
           |---Subproject 2.1

Comment: @SteveRabbit, what Tomalak's answer essentially says, is that instead of having 2 global lists: 'subprojects' and 'projects', it makes more sense to have one list 'projects', with each of the projects having a 'subprojects' list, which eliminates the need for a filter altogether. So this answer shows you how you can map the subprojects to their main projects. You're right about the "tree", **but you don't need a new viewModel**: make the tree your only viewModel.

Comment: Hi, i dont understand the syntax "$.get("projects.json").then(function (data) { ... }.done(function(data) { ... }  //.. Is it also possible to code it with 2 "for" loops : for (var i = 0; i < projects.length ; i++)  then loop over subprojects... ( for ( var x = 0, x < subprojects.length; x++ )). Can I write a knockout "computed" syntax for it, like "projects_tree = ko.computed... ?

Comment: @Steve Sure you can do that. That would have the same effect that I talk about. It would physically structure your viewmodel so that you can physically structure your view.